# Virtual Joystick - multiple actions instead of one action

Tags: android, output, action

I'm using code for virtual joystick from this [website](http://www.akexorcist.com/2012/10/android-code-joystick-controller.html).
It works fine but not for my application.
I have a problem with implementation of any action. In JoyStick.class i can control range of every direction so if the range is between specific angle and distance it returns int value of each direction.

```
  public int get4Direction() {
    if(distance > min_distance && touch_state) {
        if(angle >= 225 && angle < 315 ) {
            return STICK_UP;
        } else if(angle >= 315 || angle < 45 ) {
            return STICK_RIGHT;
        } else if(angle >= 45 && angle < 135 ) {
            return STICK_DOWN;
        } else if(angle >= 135 && angle < 225 ) {
            return STICK_LEFT;
        }
    } else if(distance <= min_distance && touch_state) {
        return STICK_NONE;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I used System.out.println to show what is not right for my application. When i put stick in specific direction for example UP and then LEFT, it generates output like that:

```
08-18 14:02:10.007  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.017  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.037  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.117  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.137  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.157  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.167  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.187  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.207  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.217  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.317  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.337  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.357  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.377  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.387  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.407  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.427  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.437  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.457  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.477  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.487  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.507  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.527  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.537  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.557  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.577  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ UP
08-18 14:02:10.587  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ LEFT
08-18 14:02:10.607  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ LEFT
08-18 14:02:10.627  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ LEFT
08-18 14:02:10.637  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ LEFT
08-18 14:02:10.657  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ LEFT
08-18 14:02:10.677  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ LEFT
08-18 14:02:10.687  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ LEFT
08-18 14:02:10.707  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2 I/System.out﹕ LEFT
```

Multiple output is the same for other directions. It's a problem for me because more complicated actions crashing app or app works very slow and i get warning:
`The application may be doing too much work on its main thread` 
Is there any way to get output only once? For example if stick is in a range of left direction, it getenerating only one line:

```
08-18 14:02:10.007  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2   I/System.out﹕ LEFT
```

if UP etc.

```
08-18 14:02:10.007  11806-11806/com.example.aidan.joysticktest2   I/System.out﹕ UP
```

It's all about checking angle and distance with if/else statement, so im looking for solution that will allow me to check this range only once for every direction or something similar. I tried everything, i was using radiobuttons, checkbuttons, variables but it wasn't helpfull and i couldn't get one line of output.

Full code:

JoyStick.class

[Source website](http://www.akexorcist.com/2012/10/android-code-joystick-controller.html)

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
RelativeLayout layout_joystick;
ImageView image_joystick, image_border;
TextView textView1, textView2, textView3, textView4, textView5;

JoyStickClass js;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textView4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    textView5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);



    layout_joystick = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_joystick);

    js = new JoyStickClass(getApplicationContext(), layout_joystick, R.drawable.redball2);
    js.setStickSize(150, 150);
    js.setLayoutSize(500, 500);
    js.setLayoutAlpha(150);
    js.setStickAlpha(100);
    js.setOffset(90);
    js.setMinimumDistance(50);


    layout_joystick.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {


            js.drawStick(arg1);
            if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                    || arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                textView1.setText("X : " + String.valueOf(js.getX()));
                textView2.setText("Y : " + String.valueOf(js.getY()));
                textView3.setText("Angle : " + String.valueOf(js.getAngle()));
                textView4.setText("Distance : " + String.valueOf(js.getDistance()));

                int direction = js.get4Direction();
                if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_UP) {
                    textView5.setText("Direction : Up");

                    System.out.println("UP");

                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_RIGHT) {
                    textView5.setText("Direction : Right");
                    System.out.println("RIGHT");

                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_DOWN) {
                    textView5.setText("Direction : Down");
                    System.out.println("DOWN");

                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_LEFT) {
                    textView5.setText("Direction : Left");
                    System.out.println("LEFT");

                } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_NONE) {
                    textView5.setText("Direction : Center");
                    System.out.println("CENTER");
                }
            } else if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                textView1.setText("X :");
                textView2.setText("Y :");
                textView3.setText("Angle :");
                textView4.setText("Distance :");
                textView5.setText("Direction :");
            }


            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

}

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="X"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Y"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="Angle"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Distance"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Direction"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_joystick"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:background="@drawable/image_button_bg" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Test `angle` variable: seems `get4Direction()` always return `STICK_UP`. And it would be much better if `angle`, `min_distance` and `touch_state` were parameters of the `get4Direction()` method, like  `get4Direction(angle, min_distance, touch_state)` because there is no information where they were changed.

Comment: Maybe i wasn't specific enough,output generates UP,LEFT,DOWN and RIGHT correctly, the problem is that i get multiple lines instead of one line and it crashing my app in some cases

Comment: It'll fire once for every `ACTION_DOWN`, and multiple times for  `ACTION_MOVE`. Seems `ACTION_MOVE` called many times. You can save previous state of `direction` and do something only once, when `direction != prevDirection`. And don't forget to update `direction` after change: `direction = prevDirection`.

Comment: Update: not `direction = prevDirection`, but `prevDirection = direction` of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it's expected behavior, because it will fire once for every `ACTION_DOWN`, and multiple times for `ACTION_MOVE`. Seems `ACTION_MOVE` called many times. To avoid process for every `ACTION_MOVE` event try add global variable:

```
int prevDirection = 0;
```

Then in `public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1)` add condition:

```
...
int direction = js.get4Direction();

if (direction != prevDirection) {
    if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_UP) {
        textView5.setText("Direction : Up");

        System.out.println("UP");
    } else if(direction == JoyStickClass.STICK_RIGHT) {  
    ...

    prevDirection = direction;
}
...
```

It's not a good solution, but it will not spoil the code of the example, which is not very good ). Ideally You should create [custom view](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html).